# how to update a column after updation of another column of same TABLE?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to update a column with help of previously updated column in phpMyAdmin. I am trying to calculate ratio by dividing advance by dep (ratio=advance/dep). I have this table :

```
#id#   #dep#  #cash#  #advance#  #ratio#
----------------------------------------
1       100     100      200        0
----------------------------------------
2       200     300      500        0 
----------------------------------------
```

I am trying this code :

```
Update 'table1' Set 'ratio'= 'advance'/'dep';
```

I expect output to be 200/100 = 2 updated in ratio when i update value of columns dep or advance in table.

Comment: Hello, you can write trigger on table 'AFTER UPDATE ' to update required column. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx

Comment: You appear to be using single quotes rather than backticks in your update statement.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql

Comment: You wrote what is your expected output , but not what is the actual output

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`CREATE TRIGGER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html) on the table to calculate and set the new ratio of the affected rows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_ratio BEFORE UPDATE ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET NEW.ratio = NEW.advance / NEW.dep;
END
```

To `UPDATE` and recalculate all records you can use the following `UPDATE` statement. You should execute this once after creating the trigger to initialize the `ratio` column.

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `ratio` = `advance` / `dep`
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b28a059f1c93bdce4671a03461e13802)

You can also use a [`CREATE VIEW`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html) to create a view of the table (without the `ratio` column). You can dynamically calculate the `ratio` column and don't need to store and recalculate the value after `UPDATE`:

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS SELECT *, advance / dep AS ratio FROM table_name;
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7c390baa938ee691ea9a0d2b81c5ab8b)

**Note:** As @P.Salmon also [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55567964/how-to-update-a-column-after-updation-of-another-column-of-same-table/55568463#comment97835689_55567964) you need to use backticks instead of single-quotes. You current `UPDATE` statement isn't valid.